# Wrong Last Execution Time sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures, dmv

I am running the following query it shows a Stored Proc that I know ran on Mon 6/6/2016 8:45 AM but the below query shows that the last execution time was 2016-05-19 12:09:23.197. Is there something I am missing here or is this an issue on the server? Everything I have found online refers to the opposite issue where people are getting reports that the proc is running when it isn't.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS s
INNER JOIN sys.procedures AS p
ON s.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
```

Comment: I have an automated report that runs, a console application I wrote calls that stored proc and generates an excel file from the results of that file. It then emails it out to a large distro of people. I double checked the report and it has data that would not have been on it unless it ran that day.

Comment: still shows last ran 2016-05-19 12:09:23.197

Comment: Defun, I just ran the proc that is in question and then ran the dm_exec_procedure_stats  and it now shows today as last executed. 
The scary about this is that if there is missing history then my purpose of doing this might be hindered. I just happened to know that proc very well so when I saw that it was a month ago ran last I knew it was wrong. The purpose of this is to see which procs are not being used for any reports and look at cleaning up the database.

Comment: Yeah the way I was going with this was saving the proc as a file and deleting that way if something went wrong I could restore it easily

Answer (score 4):

The core problem is that your query can potentially match on two different procedures in two different databases that happen to have the same `object_id`. While there isn't a reliable way to reproduce it on demand, I've seen it enough times to know it is common, and your query needs to protect against it. You can do that with a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE s.database_id = DB_ID();
```

When pulling stats for *other* databases, you can use:

```
...
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS s
INNER JOIN [other_database].sys.procedures AS p
ON s.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
WHERE s.[database_id] = DB_ID(N'other_database');
```

**Note 1**: The stats DMV does not persist data beyond service restarts, failovers, or any action that causes the procedure cache to be flushed (for the instance, for the database, or for a specific procedure). You also won't see any entry in the DMV for stored procedures that are intentionally not cached, e.g. `EXEC dbo.procedurename WITH RECOMPILE;`. So it isn't necessarily reliable to conclude that procedure A is unused simply because it isn't present in the DMV.

**Note 2**: It's possible for a database named `foo` to have different `database_id` values over its lifetime (consider the case where you drop `foo`, create another database, then create another instance of `foo`). This is unlikely, but is still worth mentioning, because you could potentially miss executions of a stored procedure that happened in the older copy of `foo`.

**Note 3**: If you want to truly measure determine the set of procedures that are unused, you will have to use heavy methods like auditing / extended events / server-side trace, or manually add logging to your stored procedures as I describe in this tip:

- [Simple process to track and log stored procedure use](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2003/simple-process-to-track-and-log-sql-server-stored-procedure-use/)

And even then, you need to leave that running for a full business cycle, to be sure you don't miss reports that are only run, say, once a quarter or other fiscal period.

Once you have identified the set of stored procedures you don't *think* are being used, don't drop them; put them in a separate schema (I'm using `zzz` here so it sorts at the bottom of the list in Object Explorer, but the name is unimportant - just make sure none of your users have it set as their default schema, and maybe even implement `DENY EXECUTE`).

```
CREATE SCHEMA zzz;
GO
ALTER SCHEMA zzz TRANSFER dbo.UnusedProcedureName1;
ALTER SCHEMA zzz TRANSFER dbo.UnusedProcedureName2;
...
```

This doesn't alleviate clutter quite as effectively as dropping the procedures, but is kind of like a very low-cost insurance policy (only the storage for the stored procedure text in the data file and backups), making it very easy to restore a procedure that was deemed unused in error.